# Invoke a SQL script containing Powershell variables

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I cant seem to get a PS variable called `$sqlParameters` to be used in an SQL script, any clues to what I am doing wrong?

**PowerShell:**

```
$sqlParameters = "powerShellVar = 'CONTOSO\cmpsvc'"
invoke-sqlcmdInvoke SQL script using Powershell variables -inputfile "c:\temp\test.sql" -serverinstance SRVSCCM\MSSQLSERVER -variable $sqlParameters
```

**SQL:**

```
CREATE LOGIN [$sqlParameters] FROM WINDOWS; 
USE test
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'$sqlParameters'
GO
```

James

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try something like this:

```
$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"  
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT `$(MyVar1) AS Var1, `$(MyVar2) AS Var2;" -Variable $MyArray
```

**or something like this:**

```
$query=@'
CREATE LOGIN [$sqlParameters] FROM WINDOWS; 
USE test
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'$sqlParameters'
GO
'@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query
```

But if you have a file, then you have to use T-sql variables only cause SQL will understand in that way only:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\Folder\SQLCmd.sql"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, actually it doe not like the variable?

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd : User or role '$name' does not exist in this database.
At line:10 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query

Comment: $name= 'CONTOSO\cmpsvc'

$query=@'

USE test
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'$name'
GO
'@

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query

Comment: @JamesAtance: Accept the answer if it helps you . That would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to use `Get-Contents` and then get Powershell to do the variable expansion, something like this:

```
$sqlParameters = 'CONTOSO\cmpsvc'"
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(Get-Contents 'my_file.sql'))
```

Or an easier way would be to use the format string. Change your file contents to this:

```
CREATE LOGIN [{0}] FROM WINDOWS; 
USE test
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'$sqlParameters'
GO
```

Then your Powershell code would be come this:

```
$sqlParameters = 'CONTOSO\cmpsvc'"
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query ((Get-Contents 'my_file.sql') -f $sqlParameters)
```

Comment: Strange as I cant get any of these to work, Does any one have another idea. All I want to do is add permissions to DB's based on a Powershell variable?